# why for some text files it works and some it wont

Tags: php, header, mime-types

I am using this to pop open a down load option but for some text files it works and for some it doesnt. please help

```
$fp = fopen($savingFolder.'/'.$fileName, 'r');
header('Content-type: '.$savingFolder.'/'.$fileName);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$savingFolder.'/'.$fileName.'"');
fpassthru($fp);
```

I made sure file is there and the content is the same as other file....mind blowing

Comment: What are the permissions on the file you're trying to open?

Comment: And by "it doesnt [work]" you mean?

Comment: it doesnt popup the download option

Comment: what file types work and what don't? Could you also add the values you passing to the header()? $savingFolder and $fileName

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set your MIME type correctly

```
$fp = fopen($savingFolder.'/'.$fileName, 'r');
header('Content-type: '.getMimeType($fileName));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fileName.'"');
fpassthru($fp); 

function getMimeType($file) {
        // MIME types array
        $mimeTypes = array(
            "323"       => "text/h323",
            "acx"       => "application/internet-property-stream",
            "ai"        => "application/postscript",
            "aif"       => "audio/x-aiff",
            "aifc"      => "audio/x-aiff",
            "aiff"      => "audio/x-aiff",
            "asf"       => "video/x-ms-asf",
            "asr"       => "video/x-ms-asf",
            "asx"       => "video/x-ms-asf",
            "au"        => "audio/basic",
            "avi"       => "video/x-msvideo",
            "axs"       => "application/olescript",
            "bas"       => "text/plain",
            "bcpio"     => "application/x-bcpio",
            "bin"       => "application/octet-stream",
            "bmp"       => "image/bmp",
            "c"         => "text/plain",
            "cat"       => "application/vnd.ms-pkiseccat",
            "cdf"       => "application/x-cdf",
            "cer"       => "application/x-x509-ca-cert",
            "class"     => "application/octet-stream",
            "clp"       => "application/x-msclip",
            "cmx"       => "image/x-cmx",
            "cod"       => "image/cis-cod",
            "cpio"      => "application/x-cpio",
            "crd"       => "application/x-mscardfile",
            "crl"       => "application/pkix-crl",
            "crt"       => "application/x-x509-ca-cert",
            "csh"       => "application/x-csh",
            "css"       => "text/css",
            "dcr"       => "application/x-director",
            "der"       => "application/x-x509-ca-cert",
            "dir"       => "application/x-director",
            "dll"       => "application/x-msdownload",
            "dms"       => "application/octet-stream",
            "doc"       => "application/msword",
            "dot"       => "application/msword",
            "dvi"       => "application/x-dvi",
            "dxr"       => "application/x-director",
            "eps"       => "application/postscript",
            "etx"       => "text/x-setext",
            "evy"       => "application/envoy",
            "exe"       => "application/octet-stream",
            "fif"       => "application/fractals",
            "flr"       => "x-world/x-vrml",
            "gif"       => "image/gif",
            "gtar"      => "application/x-gtar",
            "gz"        => "application/x-gzip",
            "h"         => "text/plain",
            "hdf"       => "application/x-hdf",
            "hlp"       => "application/winhlp",
            "hqx"       => "application/mac-binhex40",
            "hta"       => "application/hta",
            "htc"       => "text/x-component",
            "htm"       => "text/html",
            "html"      => "text/html",
            "htt"       => "text/webviewhtml",
            "ico"       => "image/x-icon",
            "ief"       => "image/ief",
            "iii"       => "application/x-iphone",
            "ins"       => "application/x-internet-signup",
            "isp"       => "application/x-internet-signup",
            "jfif"      => "image/pipeg",
            "jpe"       => "image/jpeg",
            "jpeg"      => "image/jpeg",
            "jpg"       => "image/jpeg",
            "js"        => "application/x-javascript",
            "latex"     => "application/x-latex",
            "lha"       => "application/octet-stream",
            "lsf"       => "video/x-la-asf",
            "lsx"       => "video/x-la-asf",
            "lzh"       => "application/octet-stream",
            "m13"       => "application/x-msmediaview",
            "m14"       => "application/x-msmediaview",
            "m3u"       => "audio/x-mpegurl",
            "man"       => "application/x-troff-man",
            "mdb"       => "application/x-msaccess",
            "me"        => "application/x-troff-me",
            "mht"       => "message/rfc822",
            "mhtml"     => "message/rfc822",
            "mid"       => "audio/mid",
            "mny"       => "application/x-msmoney",
            "mov"       => "video/quicktime",
            "movie"     => "video/x-sgi-movie",
            "mp2"       => "video/mpeg",
            "mp3"       => "audio/mpeg",
            "mpa"       => "video/mpeg",
            "mpe"       => "video/mpeg",
            "mpeg"      => "video/mpeg",
            "mpg"       => "video/mpeg",
            "mpp"       => "application/vnd.ms-project",
            "mpv2"      => "video/mpeg",
            "ms"        => "application/x-troff-ms",
            "mvb"       => "application/x-msmediaview",
            "nws"       => "message/rfc822",
            "oda"       => "application/oda",
            "p10"       => "application/pkcs10",
            "p12"       => "application/x-pkcs12",
            "p7b"       => "application/x-pkcs7-certificates",
            "p7c"       => "application/x-pkcs7-mime",
            "p7m"       => "application/x-pkcs7-mime",
            "p7r"       => "application/x-pkcs7-certreqresp",
            "p7s"       => "application/x-pkcs7-signature",
            "pbm"       => "image/x-portable-bitmap",
            "pdf"       => "application/pdf",
            "pfx"       => "application/x-pkcs12",
            "pgm"       => "image/x-portable-graymap",
            "pko"       => "application/ynd.ms-pkipko",
            "pma"       => "application/x-perfmon",
            "pmc"       => "application/x-perfmon",
            "pml"       => "application/x-perfmon",
            "pmr"       => "application/x-perfmon",
            "pmw"       => "application/x-perfmon",
            "pnm"       => "image/x-portable-anymap",
            "pot"       => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
            "ppm"       => "image/x-portable-pixmap",
            "pps"       => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
            "ppt"       => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
            "prf"       => "application/pics-rules",
            "ps"        => "application/postscript",
            "pub"       => "application/x-mspublisher",
            "qt"        => "video/quicktime",
            "ra"        => "audio/x-pn-realaudio",
            "ram"       => "audio/x-pn-realaudio",
            "ras"       => "image/x-cmu-raster",
            "rgb"       => "image/x-rgb",
            "rmi"       => "audio/mid",
            "roff"      => "application/x-troff",
            "rtf"       => "application/rtf",
            "rtx"       => "text/richtext",
            "scd"       => "application/x-msschedule",
            "sct"       => "text/scriptlet",
            "setpay"    => "application/set-payment-initiation",
            "setreg"    => "application/set-registration-initiation",
            "sh"        => "application/x-sh",
            "shar"      => "application/x-shar",
            "sit"       => "application/x-stuffit",
            "snd"       => "audio/basic",
            "spc"       => "application/x-pkcs7-certificates",
            "spl"       => "application/futuresplash",
            "src"       => "application/x-wais-source",
            "sst"       => "application/vnd.ms-pkicertstore",
            "stl"       => "application/vnd.ms-pkistl",
            "stm"       => "text/html",
            "svg"       => "image/svg+xml",
            "sv4cpio"   => "application/x-sv4cpio",
            "sv4crc"    => "application/x-sv4crc",
            "t"         => "application/x-troff",
            "tar"       => "application/x-tar",
            "tcl"       => "application/x-tcl",
            "tex"       => "application/x-tex",
            "texi"      => "application/x-texinfo",
            "texinfo"   => "application/x-texinfo",
            "tgz"       => "application/x-compressed",
            "tif"       => "image/tiff",
            "tiff"      => "image/tiff",
            "tr"        => "application/x-troff",
            "trm"       => "application/x-msterminal",
            "tsv"       => "text/tab-separated-values",
            "txt"       => "text/plain",
            "uls"       => "text/iuls",
            "ustar"     => "application/x-ustar",
            "vcf"       => "text/x-vcard",
            "vrml"      => "x-world/x-vrml",
            "wav"       => "audio/x-wav",
            "wcm"       => "application/vnd.ms-works",
            "wdb"       => "application/vnd.ms-works",
            "wks"       => "application/vnd.ms-works",
            "wmf"       => "application/x-msmetafile",
            "wps"       => "application/vnd.ms-works",
            "wri"       => "application/x-mswrite",
            "wrl"       => "x-world/x-vrml",
            "wrz"       => "x-world/x-vrml",
            "xaf"       => "x-world/x-vrml",
            "xbm"       => "image/x-xbitmap",
            "xla"       => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
            "xlc"       => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
            "xlm"       => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
            "xls"       => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
            "xlsx"      => "vnd.ms-excel",
            "xlt"       => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
            "xlw"       => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
            "xof"       => "x-world/x-vrml",
            "xpm"       => "image/x-xpixmap",
            "xwd"       => "image/x-xwindowdump",
            "z"         => "application/x-compress",
            "zip"       => "application/zip"
        );

        $extension = end(explode('.', $file));
        return $mimeTypes[$extension]; // return the array value
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't believe this line is correct:

```
header('Content-type: '.$savingFolder.'/'.$fileName);
```

Surely this should be

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
```

if you are serving plain text files, and an alternate appropriate MIME type if not.

Comment: The attachment filename is incorrect as well by having a slash in it

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$fp = fopen($savingFolder.'/'.$fileName, 'r');
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$fileName);
fpassthru($fp);
```

This will ensure your file will be downloaded.  If you want special treatment for every different kind of file use the `getMimeType(ext)` function that Phill Pafford posted here.